# Pull data from lotus notes database

Tags: lotus-notes

My task is to pull the data from lotusnotes database using one of the technologies.... I wanna know which is a better technology... I have already installed NotesSQL odbc driver & configured it

Comment: One of *what* technologies?  Built-in?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what exactly you're trying to do, NotesSQL will let you pull data, or you can export from Lotus Notes views in csv format, it's standard functionality. You could also code a scheduled agent to dump data at a regular intervals etc etc.

Comment: I wanna pulll data from java, I think I have three options         1. Using domino driver for jdbc 2. Using JDBC-ODBC driver(NotesSQL) & 3. using Exclipse, I am very confused with which method to use, kindly guide me for a better way

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502265/get-table-names-from-lotus-notes-database) one. My answer goes into some detail about how to access Lotus Notes using Java, setup instructions and what to read for API's supporting it.