# Retrieve data from lotus notes database view via Java

Tags: java, sql, odbc, lotus

I am trying to retrieve data from a Lotus Notes database within which I already have a view. I manage to create an ODBC connection and use this with MS Access or Excel but I'd like to create a scheduled job on a java application to inject the data in a MS SQL Server database.

I got a bit lost in all the documentation on Internet; Do 
you guys have a sample of a Java code which would allow me to
1. Connect to the database
2. "Query" the view ("SELECT * FROM..."?)
3. Get a resultset which I can iterate through
I've read that I can avoid using the Lotus SQL driver by importing the notes.jar in my project...

Thank you for your help

Comment: Just found this, having a try... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502265/get-table-names-from-lotus-notes-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and easiest way to connect to a Lotus Notes database is by using Notes API. All you need is to connect to the database, get the view and then traverse each document. You can accomplish this by including Notes API jar file into your Libraries and then you have all Notes classes at your disposal.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That's actually the solution I adopted.